# How to make next div open when previous closes using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried so far and made some pretty long code. This seems okay when one is having less then five or ten divs. But what if these are to be implemented on 20 or more than that....?

Can there be any compact form of the code I have tried to write.

( I am some novice in jquery to build complex function  but try to write these sorts. )

Any one can help..?

Fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ud574/27/

The Code is as follows.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.button').click(function() {
      $('.content').hide(500)
  $('.headOne').addClass("classRight");
 $('.content1').show(500)
 });
     $('.button1').click(function() {
     $('.content1').hide(500)
 $('.headTwo').addClass("classRight");
 $('.content2').show(500)
 });

 $('.button2').click(function() {

     $('.content2').hide(500)
 $('.headThree').addClass("classRight");
 $('.content3').show(500)
 });
 $('.button3').click(function() {

     $('.content3').hide(500)
 $('.headFour').addClass("classRight");

    $('.buttonLast').click(function() {
    $('.content').show(500)
 $('.headOne,.headTwo,.headThree, .headFour').removeClass("classRight");});
});

   });
```

---

```
       <doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title> div collapse</title>
        </head>
        <body>


   <div class="headOne"> Emplyee personal record</div>
   <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum bibendum <br />
    <div class="button">Click me</div> 
   <br />
   </div>
  <div  class="headTwo"> Emplyee personal record</div>
   <div class="content1">Pellentesque felis elit, tempor vitae dapibus facilisis, sollicitudin id diam.  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="button1">Click me</div>
  </div>
  <div  class="headThree"> Emplyee personal record</div>
  <div class="content2">Aliquam  id lectus pellentesque viverra<div class="button2">Click me</div></div> 
   <div  class="headFour"> Emplyee personal record</div>
   <div class="content3">Aliquam a magna ac lacus eget porta. Maecenas viverra mi id lectus pellentesque viverra</div>
  <div class="button3">Click me</div><br />
 <br />
  <div class="button4">Go To Previous section </div></div>


  <div class="buttonLast">Go To Previous section </div>




    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with your code a bit and simplified it a lot, using built-in jQuery functions. Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="closable"> Employee personal record
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum bibendum ullamcorper convallis.
</div></div>
<div  class="closable"> Employee personal record
<div class="content">Pellentesque felis elit, tempor vitae dapibus felis eu erat. <br />
</div></div>
<div  class="closable"> Employee personal record
<div class="content">Aliquam eget porta. Maecenas viverra mi id lectus pellentesque viverra</div></div> 
<div  class="closable"> Employee personal record
<div class="content">Aliquam a magna ac justo accumsan porttitor.</div></div>
<div class="button4">Go To Previous section </div></div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.content').first().show();
$('.closable').click(function() {
if ($(this).find('div').first().is(':visible')){
    $(this).find('div').first().hide();
    $(this).next().find('div').first().show();
}else{
    $(this).find('div').first().show();
}
});
```

});

And the CSS:

```
.content{display:block;}
.content{font-weight: normal; border: 0;display:none;}
.closable{font-weight:bold;border:1px solid #CCC;}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Webomatic for the efforts and answer you have given is good but it is somewhat similar to the accordian..
Actually if you look at the fiddle you will see that when one of the panel closes then it cannot be reopened unless user not clicks last and come down to that panel..

but in your case every panel can be opened and closed. 

I am searching modification in code not in the appearing functionality of the code. 

Each panel ( div)  must close when any one clicks the button ( close)  but cannot be opened unless top most panel is opened and then cascaded down to that panel.  

Sorry...

Comment: Anyway I am also working on that if possible may land on some solution.

Comment: Webomatic..

I made a slight change in  your code and it has started working for me 
I repalced show() with hide() code in the else { ..........hide()
}

it is now working thanks for the lovely effort and the answer...

Comment: I am now working on making upper most div visible by clicking the button a bottom most. let see if any solution... can be derived upon.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you need something similar to the Accordion control.

Have a look at jQuery UI Accordion on the following url: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Does this sound reasonable to you?

Comment: No..I have used accordion..but there is a specific problem then one cannot place click buttons in the content wrapper of accordion. 

Actually the requirement is of making such panels for the forms as soon as user fills one form and proceeds to submit the current form container closes and opens nest one, without opening the rest ones. 

If you see the html the buttons are placed in the content container...and they are visible when container opens up. 

I am looking forward to some generalized compact code...for such issue.

Comment: please read nest=next in previous comment ( sorry for the typo )

and thanks for the efforts in answering..